# How to multiple join and use withCount in Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have 3 models : Vehicle, Dealer and Province

Eloquent Relationships are as follows:

> Vehicle belongsTo Dealer
>
> Dealer hasMany Vehicles
>
> Province hasMany Dealers
>
> Dealer belongs to Province

I wanted to list the count of vehicles in each province, whereas province is linked to the vehicle only through dealer.

My code:

```
$provinces = Province::withCount('dealers')->get();

foreach ($provinces as $province) {
    echo $province->dealers_count;
}
```

This code is able to get dealers count for each province, but manipulating this code could not able to get the vehicle count for each province. Any idea

Comment: You can use `hasManyThrough` relationship for this case !!

Comment: Got it bro, that was a basic question, I am a newbie.. :)

Comment: For more details here is the [Doc link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) if you need any help i m here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your models are setup correctly, I was able to add this to my province model.

```
public function vehicles()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Vehicle::class, Dealer::class);
}
```

And then I used it like so...

```
$provinces = App\Province::with('vehicles')->get();

foreach ($provinces as $province) {
    echo $province->vehicles->count();
}
```